# Nodejs POST a FILE

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to upload a file from webpage to my backend but nothing happends. There is what i did:

Here's the form from the html file:

```
<form action="/api/bulk" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div style="width: 200px">
        <input
            type="file"
            id="user_group_logo"
            class="custom-file-input"
            accept=".xlsx, .xls, .csv"
            name="file"
        />
        <label id="user_group_label" for="user_group_logo">
            <i class="fas fa-upload"></i>&nbsp;Choose a file...
        </label>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Upload</button>
        <div class="text-center"></div>
        <div class="text-center mt-2"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

here's the routing:

```
router.route('/api/bulk').post(modelController.postBulk);
```

and here's the controller method that should upload the file to /uploads folder

```
var multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './uploads',
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
});


exports.postBulk = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log('test');
        upload(req, res, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('error');
            } else {
                console.log(req.file);
                res.send('test-req.file');
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(404).json({
            status: 'fail',
            message: err.message,
            attention: 'Cannot verify the CSV file. Call support!',
        });
    }
};
```

I don't get either a message in the console, so the method is not "accessed" somehow (I should get a "test" when I try to upload the file at least).
Any ideas, please?

Comment: what do you get as a response in the client side?

Comment: @JayadeepKM if you mean this: https://ibb.co/CQY2F5S

Comment: Looking at https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer it looks like you'd need to call upload.single() or one of the other functions on the upload object. I'm not familiar with using node on the server though.

Comment: @BogdanDoncea looks like the client is making a GET request instead of POST. You should be debugging the client code. Server side seems fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './uploads',
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
});

const postBulk = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.file);
        req.status(200).json({})
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(404).json({
            status: 'fail',
            message: err.message,
            attention: 'Cannot verify the CSV file. Call support!',
        });
    }
};

router.post(`/api/bulk`, upload.single('file'), postBulk);
```

Comment: I tried it but nothing happens. My "postBulk" method seems to not be called. I put a "console.log('test')" into try-catch and it is not shown in console while uploading a file, so there should be another problem I think

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
router.route('/api/bulk').post(upload.single('file'),modelController.postBulk);
```

upload is your constant holding multer configuration
.single is for your single file upload and .array is for multiple file upload.
please check req.file inside your controller to get the file uploaded via form

Comment: I tried it but nothing happens. My "postBulk" method seems to not be called. I put a "console.log('test')" into try-catch and it is not shown in console while uploading a file, so there should be another problem I think